# Asynchronously maintaining state integrity in Redux

Tags: redux, react-redux

Suppose I have a Redux store. Its state has the `userCoordinates` field
with the user's current coordinates:

```
{
    userCoordinates: [3.1457, 2.1728],
    ...
}
```

Then suppose the store has 20 more fields with data that depends on the
coordinates:

```
{
    ...
    nearbyFriends: ["Bob", "Jimmy"],
    nearbyShops: ["Point & Click tools", "Bobby Ray's"],
    address: "42 Enth Street, Townsville, Countryland",
    weather: "Cloudy",
    ...
}
```

Values in all of these fields are loaded over HTTP from
various services, one separate request for each field.

Now suppose the user's geolocation is updated, and an action is dispatched that
changes the value of `userCoordinates`:

```
dispatch(updateCoords([1.6180, 1.4142]));
```

Now `userCoordinates` has new coordinates and all 20 other fields have invalid data.

1. If the goal is just to keep *all* the fields "eventually" valid, where do I make the requests to fetch the new data?
2. How the method changes if I use React-Redux and there are lots of components using many different combinations of these fields, with some fields used by more than one component and some fields not used at all?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how this is architected, I would do one of two things.

1: Compare states in your reducer. If there is a change in the user coordinates in the state, you could add something to the store like `updateNeeded: true`, then have a check wherever you are loading your other data so that if `updateNeeded` is true, you fire an ajax call to go get new data from the server.

2: If it is set up the right way, you could used `componentWillReceiveProps` to compare the props. If there is a change in `userCoordinates`, dispatch an action to go get the other data fields.

Of course, this would just be easier if you could just get all the data with one call...

Comment: I've tried this approach already and it's not scalable in my experience. Imagine having 40 components and writing and maintaining those prop/mount hooks all over the code! Not to mention dealing with duplicate requests. At that point I would be way better off with the standard React.